# Does json count as a data structure or not? If not, what is the essence of JSON?

Tags: json, data-structures, tree, computer-science, dataformat

Very confused about JSON.

In data structure books, the author only writes about how to implement a tree with list or linked list, but not a single word around JSON.

I've used JSON for years, but more and more confused about this ...string?

It is very simple to indicate a tree with JSON. The question is: as this is so easy, why don't we use JSON to implement a tree?

Is it because when the book was written, the JSON still not invented?

So, what is the essence of JSON?

Is it a string as a traversal result for human reading, or a data format for machine storage?

Or, something else?

Answer (score 2):

> **What is Json:**

Json is data format, which represents the objects in memory, it is a text serialization format. There are other formats like XML, which is also text serialization. There are other binary serialization formats, which are better in wire transfer being compressed.

> **What is Data Structure:**

Data structures are arangement of physical data in the memory which have time and space complexity associated, which helps arranging the data in the efficient format with access, traversal and search. Data structures are basis of variety of algorithms, which helps in solving real life problems. Data structures are the de-serialized version of data stored in Json

> **In Simple words :**

In memory the data is allocated using data structures, on network it travels in the serialized format and deserialized at other end point. This is done since http as a protocol cannot carry the state, it is converted to serialized / wire format.
Text formats can also be allocated to string data type, persisted to file / database, but ultimately converting to data structures like `List`, `Dictionary` provides many more useful methods

> **Trivia:**

Atleast in Python, dictionary reflects json format, though you cannot directly assign, since json is ultimately string, it has to be converted using deserialization json apis

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which helps me feel clearer about these concepts.

Comment: I noticed there's a key concept in this answer: 'http as a protocol cannot carry the state'. Deeper digging needed lol:) .One question draws 100 ones ;)

Comment: You can dig deeper, what I mean is http is a stateless protocol which means has no scope of remembering and restoring the state and also state refers to object memory where http cannot carry the object memory. That's why data needs to be serialized while transferring over http protocol and is deserialized at the application end point. If you have doubts ask question / clarification, don't assume that to be incorrect by default

Comment: This reply exactly answered what I'm wondering: the logical relationship between 'HTTP is a stateless protocol' and 'data should be serialized while transferring through network cable'.

Answer (score 0):

Some one says that the best way to solve a question is just asking the question.
Hours after asking the question on stack over flow, I found out a possibility:

When we are talking about 'data structure', that 'data structure', this 'thing' in fact does not exist in the world of reality. A data structure is an abstract concept, not a concrete thing. It exists only in the human imagination. In the area of implementation esp. when programming with a computer, this 'data structure' is made up of a bunch of complex things which including data definition and the operations could be applied to the data. Data structure does exist as a abstract concept, but you have to implement it to a concrete serialized string, such as some code of a programming language, a data base table, an excel spread sheet, a JSON or YAML string... etc,.

So, I'd say, nothing is important what the JSON file is. It's just a description of a ABSTRACT DATA STRUCTURE. The purpose of the using of JSON or any other thing like this (XML, HTML, YAML,...even a picture, a text file, an piece of audio recording of a person who is telling the programmer what the data structure is...), is to tell "YOU" the description of the data itself, but the 'describing way'  is not the data itself. The data does not exist.

And then, when you concrete the data structure in the mind, in the brain, you should tell it to the computer. The computer is very simple a machine which can't understand what the serialized string mean. You(human) should turn this strings to a way which a computer could understand. And this, is what the 'data structure courses' concentrates on.

Further on, even if we use json(such as a python dict data type) to indicate a tree, there are much more things to do to complete the whole programming. The data description is not data itself, let alone the operations on the data.

Comment: Data structure is real with physical memory allocated. Abstract data types are created using Data structures, that's like class in Java, C#, which defines as domain